# I am getting image from sdcard and displaying it on imageview now i want to insert this image in database but its not stored in db

Tags: android, database, image, insert

I am creating an app for a customer store their image and detail. I am browsing the image by camera or sd card. I am getting the image in `ImageView` by sdcard, but when I insert it in database it is not inserting in the image column in database.

I am clicking on the sd card button to browse for an image. Now this image in show in `ImageView`.

```
Button btnsdcard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.custbtnimage);
    btnsdcard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_SELECT_IMAGE);
        }
    });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            try {
                InputStream imgstream = getContentResolver()
                        .openInputStream(selectedImage);
                Bitmap btm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imgstream);
                ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagecust);
                img.setImageBitmap(btm);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                btm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bo);
                byte[] custimage = bo.toByteArray();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {                 
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "file not fount",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }   }
    }
```

now when  i am click save button othewr data store in database but image column empty in database and i am not get any error.

```
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("ParserError")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name = custname.getText().toString();
            String address = custaddress.getText().toString();
            Long pincode = Long.parseLong(custpincode.getText().toString());
        String city = custcity.getText().toString();


            byte[] image=custimage;

            Customerprofile profile = new Customerprofile();
            profile.setName(name);
            profile.setAddress(address);
            profile.setPincode(pincode);
            profile.setCity(city);
            profile.setImage(image);

            insertcust(profile);
                        }

        private void insertcust(Customerprofile profile) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DatabaseHelper mydbhelper = new DatabaseHelper(Myimage.this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = mydbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_NAME, profile.getName());
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_ADDRESS, profile.getAddress());
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_PINCODE, profile.getPincode());
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_CITY, profile.getCity());
            values.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_IMAGE, profile.getImage());

            long adcid = db.insert(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null,
                    values);

            db.close();


        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone help me give me solution to store my `ImageView` image in database.

Answer (score 0):

You really should store the image somewhere other than the DB, and just put the path to the image in the DB.

If you really want to put it in the database, you need to create a column with the `BLOB` type to store it in (I mention this since you don't show your DB structure).

Then you need to convert the image to a byte array and then save it to the db.  Looking through your code, it looks like you are doing all that...

Found your issue.  You are using local variables and then trying to reference them outside their scope.  You have `byte[] custimage = bo.toByteArray();` in your `onActivityResult` and then try to use it `byte[] image=custimage;` in your `onClick` when it is out of scope.

Declare `custimage` as a class field so that all methods can access it `byte[] custimage;`, change the occurence in `onActivityResult` to `custimage = bo.toByteArray();` and it should start working.